# try_files not fixing 404 in EC2 container

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, dockerfile

I've seen multiple answers to make `nginx` server route an Angular application properly, but no solution has worked for me yet.

I ran `nginx -s reload` after adding `try_files` to `etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

The complete `nginx.conf` file looks like this

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

   server {
      location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
   }
}
```

Also I've seen multiple answers making changes to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` but my nginx server simply does not have that folder.

Could it be the way I am deploying to my server? For that I am using docker as follows:

```
FROM node:alpine as BUILD
WORKDIR /my-web
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=BUILD /my-web/dist/app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and the output path in `angular.json` is `"outputPath": "dist/app"`

The url of the app is `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com` but refreshing pages and manually navigating to pages still does not work.

I am using Angular 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in this question:

[Angular Nginx Docker 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318079/angular-nginx-docker-404/56318111#comment108424845_56318111)

I was changing `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` but I added the same `server` and `try_files` configuration to this file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`